# Show that the cylinder is not ambient isotopic to the Mobius band.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Here is my definition for ambient isotopy:

We say if there is an orientation preserving piecewise linear homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ (or replace $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $S^3$) for two knots, say, $K_1$ and $K_2$ then the two knots are $\textit{equivalent}$, or $f$ is an $\textit{ambient isotopy}$, such that $f(K_1)=K_2$.

Obviously it doesn't have to be in terms of knots specifically. 
I want to show why the cylinder (which is a closed ribbon with an odd number of twists including $0$) is not ambient isotopic to the Mobius band (which is a closed ribbon with an odd number of twists).

Comment: Ambient isotopy makes sense for homeomorphic spaces (embedding of the same space): the Moebius band and the cylinder are not homeomorphic. Spaces that are not homeomorphic cannot be isotopic. (And probably for the cylinder you mean a closed ribbon with and *even* number of twists).

Comment: What could make sense would be to show that the cylinder with $0$ twists is not ambient isotopic to the cylinder with $2$ twists...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Consider what would happen to the boundary.